# Mongoose Get Multiple Object Inside A Loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get multiple objects from MongoDB with using mongoose. I have two main tables named user and order.

The user has an array named order history and order history contains orders.

When I push order to the orders array, order pushes successfully. But when I want to reach orders from outside of the loop, my array has got nothing because of the async operation happened inside the loop.

## CODE

```
userModel.findOne({'username': username }, function (err, user) {
        if(user){
            var orders = [] 

            for(var i=0;i<user.orderHistory.length;i++){
                var orderId = user.orderHistory[i].orderId

                var order = orderModel.findOne({'id': orderId}).exec()
                
                order.then(function(order){
                    orders.push(order)
                })              
            }

            orders.then(function(order){
                console.log(order)
            })
        }
    })
```

How can I reach orders outside of the loop? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an async function instead, and `await` each order.

```js
userModel.findOne({ username }, async function (err, user) {
  if (!user) return;
  const orders = [];
  for (const { orderId: id } of user.orderHistory) {
    const order = await orderModel.findOne({ id }).exec();
    orders.push(order);
  }
  console.log(orders);
})
```

Comment: Might be good to also explain why the problematic code didn't work.